# Google cloud platform | 100% API error rate when using google translation API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-translate, google-translation-api

I've been using google cloud platform for a year with breaks from time to time. I only needed Google Translate API, which was working fine until recently. I don't know what exactly changed from Google`s side because nothing has changed from my side. I'm still using the API key for translating documents in MemoQ. Now, when MemoQ sends requests to Google servers, it doesn't return translation. 
I don't know the technical details but will try to explain : I created a Google cloud account, set up billing, created a project, added Google Cloud translation API to it, the generated API key needs to be told to MemoQ - a tool for translation, then when MemoQ sends a request it should get a reply from Google with translated text, but now I don't get the translated text back.

At Google Cloud Console I can see the history of API use, I see that requests from MemoQ are coming to Google Cloud, but the Error rate is 100%.

I don't know what could be done here. I tried setting up a different API key, using a different account, but nothing helped. I can't consult Google Cloud tech support because I'm using a basic plan of Google Cloud.

[image: Google Cloud Console API Errors]

[image]

I've downloaded the .CSV file for errors, it has several lines as follows:

> time,google.cloud.translate.v2.TranslateService.TranslateText
>
> 2019-11-14T11:25:53.658Z,1
>
> 2019-12-02T07:49:53.658Z,1
>
> 2019-12-02T11:25:53.658Z,1

I installed Fiddler as proposed by @AmanKejriwal, I tried to translate something, I can see the requests at GC Dashboard, but I only found very little evidence of google in fiddler. I also tried using Microsoft machine translation that I also have set up in MemoQ, but didn't find many Microsoft translation-related items either.

[image]

A closer look at these items didn't give me any more information.

[image]

All the abovementioned Google-related items belong to "Chrome" process though. None of them belong to "MemoQ" process. The only item belonging to "MemoQ" process is the one highlighted at the screenshot, which is a request for updates.

[image]

Comment: Can you share the error code and the JSON response please?

Comment: Alternatively, you can share a screenshot o your Google API dashboard.

Comment: @AmanKejriwal I added a screenshot, don't know if it will be any good.

Comment: Since you do see the requests failing at GT dashboard along with the timestamp, my guess is that you are not using Fiddler correctly. 

Fiddler is a proxy. So you have to set your app to use Fiddler as a proxy. On startup Fiddler changes the WinINET proxy settings which your app may or may not respect.

You can use Echo Mirage tool that will give you info for communications (inbound/outbound) for desktop apps.

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/projects/echomirage.oldbutgold.p/

This should help you monitor all network communication from MemoQ as well as open and change payloads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue solved. 
I contacted MemoQ support, they asked to send them a log file. After analyzing it, they said that this issue is probably caused by exceeding machine translation quota. The advice was to increase the quota in billing. I've never exceeded a quota, but by looking at my account's billing info I found out that my billing account was stopped so I activated it back again. Since then everything went back to normal. 
Thank you for trying to help me solve my problem!

Answer (score 1):

To me it seems more like a MemoQ issue than of GT. All things considered, I would suggest that you install Fiddler and see the raw request data sent by MemoQ to Google. Since Google Translate API accept only plain text or HTML (not even XML), I think the problem lies in how MemoQ is processing the content here.

Assuming that you are feeding a file to MemoQ, the request data formatting can be really off causing all kinds of check failures.

Comment: For some reason, I can't find any requests from MemoQ relating to GC and translation. But maybe I'm not using Fiddler correctly?

Comment: Since you do see the requests failing at GT dashboard along with the timestamp, my guess is that you are not using Fiddler correctly. Fiddler is a proxy. So you have to set your app to use Fiddler as a proxy. On startup Fiddler changes the WinINET proxy settings which your app may or may not respect. You can use Echo Mirage tool that will give you info for communications (inbound/outbound) for desktop apps. –

sourceforge.net/projects/echomirage.oldbutgold.p 
<>
This should help you monitor all network communication from MemoQ as well as open and change payloads.